# hidden input breaks the css style

Tags: css

Hello I've got this style

```
.portfolio-filters input[type=checkbox]:checked{background:#cb2127}
```

and my code is

```
<ul class="portfolio-filters list-unstyled">
     <li>
         <div class="form-group">
             <input id="custom-software" type="checkbox" name="" value="" checked="">
              <label for="custom-software">Custom Software</label>
         </div>
    </li>
```

The problem is that inside this div `form-group` if I add hidden input  fields, it breaks the CSS.

Do you have an idea how I can fix the problem?

Comment: I don't understand the problem clearly, would you provide us with an example on jsfiddle?

Comment: Not sure what your question is, but i noticed an issue with your code, if you are using bootstrap(form-group) then input type="checkbox must be nested within label tags. Does that solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

How do you hide input? Your should use `display:none` if you don't want to maintain its position